# Create another column based on the order of dates of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the following dataframe:

```
 account_id contract_id date_activated
0   1   AAA 2021-01-05
1   1   ADS 2020-12-12
2   1   ADGD    2021-02-03
3   2   HHA 2021-03-05
4   2   HAKD    2021-03-06
5   3   HADSA   2021-05-01
```

I want the following results:

```
 account_id contract_id date_activated  Renewal Order
0   1   ADS 2020-12-12  Original
1   1   AAA 2021-01-05  1st
2   1   ADGD    2021-02-03  2nd
3   2   HHA 2021-03-05  Original
4   2   HAKD    2021-03-06  1st
5   3   HADSA   2021-05-01  Original
```

The column I want to create is "Renewal Order". Each account can have multiple contracts. The condition is based on the each account (account_id) and the order in which the contracts are activated (date_activated). The first contract will be identified as "Original" while the succeeding contracts as "1st", "2nd", and so on.

Here's the dictionary of the original dataframe:

```
{'account_id': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 3},
 'contract_id': {0: 'AAA',
  1: 'ADS',
  2: 'ADGD',
  3: 'HHA',
  4: 'HAKD',
  5: 'HADSA'},
 'date_activated': {0: Timestamp('2021-01-05 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2020-12-12 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2021-02-03 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2021-03-05 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2021-03-06 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2021-05-01 00:00:00')}}
```

Here's the dictionary for the result:

```
{'account_id': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 3},
 'contract_id': {0: 'ADS',
  1: 'AAA',
  2: 'ADGD',
  3: 'HHA',
  4: 'HAKD',
  5: 'HADSA'},
 'date_activated': {0: Timestamp('2020-12-12 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2021-01-05 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2021-02-03 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2021-03-05 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2021-03-06 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2021-05-01 00:00:00')},
 'Renewal Order': {0: 'Original',
  1: '1st',
  2: '2nd',
  3: 'Original',
  4: '1st',
  5: 'Original'}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas-dataframe-sort-values) to ensure contracts are in the correct order + [`groupby cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-cumcount) to get each order number, then [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas-series-map) or [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas-series-apply) a function to convert numbers to desired string values:

```
def format_order(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 'Original'
    suffix = ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th'][min(n % 10, 4)]
    if 11 <= (n % 100) <= 13:
        suffix = 'th'
    return str(n) + suffix


df = df.sort_values(['account_id', 'date_activated']).reset_index(drop=True)
# apply
df['Renewal Order'] = df.groupby('account_id').cumcount().apply(format_order)
```

or

```
df = df.sort_values(['account_id', 'date_activated']).reset_index(drop=True)
# map
df['Renewal Order'] = df.groupby('account_id').cumcount().map(format_order)
```

```
   account_id contract_id date_activated Renewal Order
0           1         ADS     2020-12-12      Original
1           1         AAA     2021-01-05           1st
2           1        ADGD     2021-02-03           2nd
3           2         HHA     2021-03-05      Original
4           2        HAKD     2021-03-06           1st
5           3       HADSA     2021-05-01      Original
```

Answer (score 1):

One more option:

```
df = df.sort_values(['account_id', 'date_activated']).reset_index(drop=True)
df['Renewal Order'] = df.groupby('account_id').cumcount().apply(
    lambda n: 'Original' if n == 0 else "%d%s" % (n, "tsnrhtdd"[(n//10 % 10 != 1)*(n % 10 < 4)*n % 10::4]))
```

Comment: I knew the golfed code option would make an appearance.

Answer (score 0):

We can first find [cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) by grouping `account_id` and then using [np.select](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) we can provide conditions if `Renewal Order is 0 then replace it with Original` and following conditions.
We can scale it to `3rd, 4th and so on`.
I have also put a condition `default=unorignal` if we need any default value.

**Code**

```
df = df.sort_values(['account_id', 'date_activated']).reset_index(drop=True)
df['Renewal Order'] = df.groupby('account_id').cumcount()
conditions = [
    df['Renewal Order']==0,
    df['Renewal Order']==1,
    df['Renewal Order']==2
]
choices = ['Original', '1st', '2nd']
df['Renewal Order'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='unOriginal') ## remove default if not required
df
```

**Output**

```
account_id      contract_id date_activated  Renewal Order
0   1           ADS         2020-12-12      Original
1   1           AAA         2021-01-05      1st
2   1           ADGD        2021-02-03      2nd
3   2           HHA         2021-03-05      Original
4   2           HAKD        2021-03-06      1st
5   3           HADSA       2021-05-01      Original
```